# Would someone explain, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to boolean" in this context?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

The homework question I'm working on is asking me to return true if all the elements in a list have the same value, or false if any of the elements have different values. I wrote the following code to accomplish this:

```
    public static boolean allSame (double[] list) {
        double sameReference = list[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list [i+1] = sameReference)
                continue;
            else return false; 
        return true;
        }
    }
```

It seems to work well, except I'm running into a single error in line 3: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to boolean`

Could someone explain what is being converted from a double too Boolean, and what I wrote that is converting it? How would I go about resolving this error? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Look carefully at `list [i+1] = sameReference`.   Q:  What actually is it?  A: it is an **assignment** expression.  Q: What is its value?  A:  the value of `sameReference`.  Q: And what is that?  A: a `double`.  Q: What do you need in an `if` condition?  A: a `boolean` ... not a `double`.

Comment: sameReference represents the first element of the array. It's meant to be the "reference" number that all the subsequent numbers need to match. My thought process is, if the subsequent elements are all equal to the value of the first element, then they're considered the same, and the loop continues. So sameReference, or list[0], must equal list[i+1] for the loop to continue.

Comment: I know that.   But what is the operator that you should use to compare two numbers?  Hint: it is NOT `=`.  The `=` operator is the **assignment** operator.  You need the `==` operator!

Comment: and the `{}` after `else` statement is useless

Comment: Actually it is more than that.  The `{}` is an unreachable statement, as is the `return` that follows it.  Basically the method's block structure is all messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the catch zhang-yuan, and for the answer Stephen. I'm still processing the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use `==` instead of `=` for equal

```
if (list [i+1] == sameReference)
```

Second, you shouldn't check list [i+1] when i starts from 1.

Third, you shouldn't use `continue`

```
public static boolean allSame (double[] list) {
    double sameReference = list[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list [i] != sameReference)
            return false; 
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can think about whether to check the size of the list first.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have given the OP a complete solution.  I say unfortunately, because people who are learning to code more learn more from making mistakes and finding, understanding and correcting them than they do from reading a correct solution.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I understand now that I used an assignment operator instead of an equality operator for the question. I understand the code you've sent here but I do have a question - what if the array has a length of zero? I just ran a test case with an empty array and was thrown a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I understand what the exception means, but I'm not sure how to account for this without a try-catch.

Comment: @Pallu08: Well, you've already got code in there to find the length of the list, so you should be able to do something using that at the start of the method...